# Вынести div из блока с overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть панель навигации, фиксированная.

В ней есть `div` со свойством `ovelflow`, в котором размещаются дочерние блоки и надо из него с помощью Jquery перетаскивать блоки по всей странице, но при перетаскивании они пропадают - их становится не видно.

Если добавить `draggable({ revert: true, helper: "clone" });` то всё работает, только оригинал остается на своем месте. Как сделать чтоб при перемещении оригинал пропадал, а при возвращении helper на место опять появлялся?

[Пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nu5gmame/)

Comment: Здравствуйте! **1).** На JSFiddle можно нажать кнопку **Tidy** и код будет приведен в порядок. **2).** Я могу попробовать полностью это реализовать на чистом javascript, без jQuery, вас устроит такой вариант?

Comment: Про JSFiddle теперь буду знать, спасибо! А на js, я думаю, не стоит буду мучать то, что есть!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел решение - при начале перетаскивания делаем оригинальный объект полностью прозрачным, а при окончании возвращаем ему нормальную прозрачность

```
$(".in-inner").draggable({
  revert: true,
  helper: "clone"
}).on('drag', function(){
$(this).css('opacity','0');
}).on('dragstop', function(){
$(this).css('opacity','1');
});
```